# Span and vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

if $V$ is a vector space and $\Omega$ set of vectors $v\in V$. and $\langle \rangle $mean linear span ,and X vector space.
what does mean linear span, what is the difference between the following definitions, please:

$$
X=\langle v_i |v_i\in \Omega\rangle
$$
 $$
X=\langle v_i :v_i\in \Omega\rangle
$$
 $$
X=\langle v_i  ,v_i\in \Omega\rangle
$$
I mean the difrence between $|,:, ","$?, because i read about the same think in difrrent books and paper and evry one use diffrent notation, 
thanks.

Comment: Those three symbols mean "such that".

Comment: The three notations means the same : the subspace generated by the vectors in $\Omega$.

Comment: ok thanks for the help, but if $\Omega$ contains 3 vector $v_1,v_2,v_3$ then we can say  $$
X= \langle v_1,v_2,v_3\rangle
$$

Comment: the use of "," to represent "such that" is not common at all, and it can be ambiguous as you had seen. In general the use of "," means "and".

Comment: if $\omega =v_1,v_2,v_3$ then$$
X=\langle v_i : v_i\in \Omega\rangle
=\langle v_1,v_2,v_3\rangle$$